# Is it possible to coordinate castings this way?

Tags: magic, gurps-4e, gurps-dungeon-fantasy

Follow-on to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165034/can-energy-from-lend-energy-be-banked-like-that-from-paut/165055#165055), is it possible to coordinate (synchronize) the castings of spells such that if Alice the Mage is casting a spell that needs more FP than she has available (from her own FP, plus Energy Reserve if in play, plus Powerstone/Manastone/Power Item), Bob the Younger (her apprentice and assistant) can Lend Energy at just the right time to keep Alice from having to use HP (at a skill penalty of -1 per HP used) to cast the spell (with the penalty potentially increasing the inherent risk of casting related to critical failures)?

Sure, that's what Share Energy is for (though the cost of two points per point used by the recipient is an issue, as is the limit of 5 FP shared) -- but if you're playing under *Dungeon Fantasy/DFRPG* that spell isn't available.

So, can Bob help Alice this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's something Lend Energy cannot do.

As you wrote, Bob could learn the more advanced spell Share Energy to help Alice that way (assuming that that spell is known and available to Bob in the campaign situation).

It sounds like maybe you just missed it, though. Share Energy is in the Dungeon Fantasy RPG Spells book on page 39.

The spells are broken up in their abilities and costs to intentionally require more learning and more energy if you are going to gain the benefits of being able to conveniently and immediately coordinate to share energy and to let a caster use more mana than their own means allow. In this way there are some interesting tradeoffs and limits.

Comment: Is that one of the *DFRPG* books, or the original *DF* PDFs, and if the latter, which?  I don't have all of those, and don't have the full *DFRPG* (though my GM does).  Further, this is Healing College -- available only to Clerics, in *DF/DFRPG* -- is that listed on the Cleric spell list?  If not, nobody can actually learn it unless it's the in only prerequisite path for a spell in another college.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: That's in the Spells book of DFRPG, on p. 39. It's available to clerics, druids and wizards; for wizards, it has a prerequisite of Lend Energy.

Comment: Hmm.  I might need to have another little email chat with my GM, then.  It's not on the Cleric spell list in *DF:1*, which is all I have to go on (I've got a scattering of *DF* PDFs), and I asked if it was possible to learn it...

Comment: Thanks, @JohnDallman, for the page reference.